# no such table: Users

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I added a database to my game and when I check in Unity Editor everything works fine, but when I run the game on my phone it gives an error no such table: Users although the database has this table

My code

```
    private void ConnectData()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        _path = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "russianWords.bytes"); //Path to datab
#elif PLATFORM_ANDROID
        _path = Application.persistentDataPath + "russianWords.bytes";
        if (!File.Exists(_path))
        {
                Debug.Log("4");
            string timlesPath = "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets" + "russianWords.bytes";
            Debug.Log(timlesPath);
            WWW load = new WWW(timlesPath);
            while (!load.isDone) { }
            File.WriteAllBytes(_path, load.bytes);
        }

#endif

        _dbConnection = new SqliteConnection("URI=file:" + _path);
        _dbConnection.Open();
        if (_dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            m_sqlCmd = new SqliteCommand();
            m_sqlCmd.Connection = _dbConnection;
        }
    }

private void CheckEndGame()
{
    if(ResultWords.Count - 1 >= GameManager.Instance.TargetWordsAmount)
    {
        string words = "";
        foreach(var p in ResultWords)
        {
            if(p != "КОЛА")
                words += p + ", ";
        }

        ScrambleInterface.Interface.OpenResultPanel(words);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you access that table. What is `while (!load.isDone) { }` supposed to do?

Comment: This loop will run until the table is loaded.

Comment: Yeah but `load.isDone` isn't going to change inside the loop, is it?

Comment: Yes, if the cycle changes, then the code will go further

Comment: @Charlieface the **obsolete** [`WWW`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) runs async so `isDone` will become `true` on a separate `Task`.

Comment: You seem to not show us the code where this error is actually thrown ... somewhere you are trying to access a table `Users` which doesn't exist in your database ...

Comment: Is it possible that the WWW fails since you look in the wrong place? You don't have any check for success or failure ... sounds like `load.bytes` is simply an empty array ....

Comment: @derHugo Unless `load.isDone` is doing interlocked memory access (either `volatile` or Interlocked.Read` etc), it is simply going to be elided into an infinite loop

Comment: @Charlieface as said it is running async and will be done at some point ;) it is basically like an async Task. otherwise the app would completely freeze and OP wouldn't get an error ;)

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like your [`WWW` (which is long **obsolete** btw)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) simply fails since you look in the wrong place for your file.

You don't have any check for success or failure so I would simply claim: The load fails and therefore `load.bytes` is an empty `byte[]`. -> Nothing exists in that database at all.

Also you are e.g. using

```
_path = Application.persistentDataPath + "russianWords.bytes";
```

which is a path where your app doesn't even have access -> you might already get an exception for the `File.Exists`.

---

As said `WWW` is obsolete. You also shouldn't use blocking calls for this kind of stuff. I wouldn't even use a WebRequests here at all but rather simply direct `FileIO` like e.g.

```
    private void Connect()
    {
        Task.Run(async () => await ConnectAsync());
    }

    private async Task ConnectAsync()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        _path = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "russianWords.bytes");
#elif PLATFORM_ANDROID
        _path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "russianWords.bytes");
        if (!File.Exists(_path))
        {
            Debug.Log("4");
            var sourcePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "russianWords.bytes");
            Debug.Log(sourcePath);
            
            await CopyFileAsync(sourcePath, _path);
        }
#endif

        _dbConnection = new SqliteConnection("URI=file:" + _path);
        _dbConnection.Open();
        if (_dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            m_sqlCmd = new SqliteCommand();
            m_sqlCmd.Connection = _dbConnection;
        }
    }

    private async Task CopyFileAsync(string sourcePath, string destinationPath)
    {
        using (var source = File.Open(sourcePath))
        {
            using(var destination = File.Create(destinationPath))
            {
                await source.CopyToAsync(destination);
            }
        }
    }
```